# Populating a dropdown list in Cakephp from database values

Tags: database, cakephp, listbox

I'm trying to populate the values in a dropdown list in Cakephp v2.6.1.
The values are being retrieved, but the form helper is not creating dropdown listboxes as expected: All I am getting displayed on the form is the Submit button - The id fields are send as hidden fields to the web page. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

**Coursemembership controller**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class CoursemembershipsController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');
...
    public function add() {



        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Coursemembership->create();
            if ($this->Coursemembership->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The coursemembership has been saved.'));
                if ($this->Coursemembership->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The coursemembership could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }
            }
        }
        $students = $this->Coursemembership->Student->find('list');
        $courses = $this->Coursemembership->Course->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('students', 'courses'));

    }
```

**Add view**

```
<div class="coursememberships form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Coursemembership'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.id'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Course.id'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

**Variables (from the debug add-in)**

```
   View Variables
        students(array)
            1Cromwell
            2Lionheart
            3Knight
            7four
            8five
            9six
            10seven
            11eight
        courses(array)
            1Applied Speliology
            2Aggravated aggrandisement
            3Crossword Puzzles 101
            5Aggravated aggrandisement
            6Applied Speliology
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the field names for your inputs properly. The `id` field is the primary key by convention and will be added as a hidden field (usually used for editing, so your Model knows what id to alter).

You should add the fields as they are set in the Coursemembership datasource (probably a database table called `coursememberships`, if you're following convention for database design). This should show the fields you need and save the proper data:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Coursemembership');

echo $this->Form->input('Coursemembership.student_id');
echo $this->Form->input('Coursemembership.course_id');

echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

Everything you want to save should go to the `Coursemembership` model. You should only need to save anything to the `Student` or `Course` model if you'd actually wanted to add a new student or course to your application. For assigning a membership of a Student to a Course, the above code should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem of the comboboxes. The data is not being saved correctly (specifically the data on the join table) but I guess I'll have to ponder that